# Get {{#index}} parent of the first for loop inside the second for loop in JSrender

Tags: html, jsrender, jsviews

I have two for loops, the second one is inside the first one, I'd like to get the #index of the first loop inside the second loop.

this is my code:

```
    {{for parentObject}}
      {{for childObject}}
           <input id="myId{{:#indexParent}}{{:#index}}"/>
      {{/for}}
    {{/for}}
```

I've tried this code:

```
    {{for parentObject ~parent=#index}}
      {{for childObject}}
           <input id="myId{{:~parent}}{{:#index}}"/>
      {{/for}}
    {{/for}}
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your objects are arrays. The ~parent=#index needs to be on the "item" template block - (the contents of {{for outerArray}}).

```
{{for parentObject}}
  {{for childObject  ~parent=#index}}
       <input id="myId{{:~parent}}{{:#index}}"/>
  {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

You were picking up the index in the context one level too high.

Comment: Yes my objects are arrays. So I tried this solution but it doesnt work! it displays nothing.
Thanks.

Comment: If it displays nothing, then your childObject or parentObject iteration is not working. You should just test using "aaa{{for parentObject}}xxx{{for childObject}}yyy{{/for}}{{/for}}bbb", first. Does that output "aaabbb" or "aaaxxxyyy...bbb" or what? Maybe your issue is 'higher up'. After that try something like: "aaa{{for parentObject}}{{:#index}}xxx{{for childObject}}{{:#index}}xxxyyy{{/for}}{{/for}}bbb"

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
{{for parentObject ~parent=#index}}
  {{for childObject}}
       <input id="myId{{:#parent.index}}"/>
  {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```